# Setting cmd-mode bindings in inputrc for vi editing-mode

Tags: bash, vi, readline

I am using vi key bindings in `.inputrc` with

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Then I would like to add new bindings for command mode, namely use `K` and `J` to perform forward and reverse search in history of what I currently have typed. I have tried:

```
C-K:history-search-backward
C-J:history-search-forward
```

...but this sets <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> to be bound to this search when in insert mode, rather than plain <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> in command mode.

If i use:

```
K:history-search-backward
J:history-search-forward
```

...then it is again in insert mode that letters K and J are bound to search (which is really unwanted)

What is the syntax for setting a new command mode key in `.inputrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this](http://www.usenix.org.uk/content/bash.html#input), I conclude that it's not the keystroke that should be changed in `.inputrc`, but (quite logically) the context in which it applies:

```
$if mode=vi
set keymap vi-command
K:history-search-backward
J:history-search-forward
$endif
```

Now there's another difficulty that in command mode, the cursor can be at most at the last character of the line and not at the one-past-last as in insert mode, so the searched pattern does not include the last character. E.g., if you enter `fin` then issue <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, it searches `fi` and could complete to `file` as well as `find`.

I don't think there's an efficient cure for this, so I'll have to get used to insert-mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> as most convenient way.